# Java 8 JRE & Puppet

Tags: java, vagrant, puppet

How to add Java 8 JRE to Ubuntu 14.04 Vagrant box with additionals repositories? I try but without any success.

```
# ElasticSearch
class { 'java':
  distribution => 'jre',
  package      => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
}

class { 'elasticsearch':
  java_install => true,
  repo_version => '5.x',
  manage_repo  => true,
  require => Class['java']
}->
elasticsearch::instance { 'es-01':
  config => {
    'cluster.name' => 'vagrant_elasticsearch',
    'index.number_of_replicas' => '0',
    'index.number_of_shards'   => '1',
    'network.host' => '0.0.0.0'
  },
  init_defaults => { }, # Init defaults hash
}->
```

I don't know how to install new Java with Puppet. I don't have experiance with it.
Could someone help me? Is this possible?

@Edit

```
==> default: Error: Could not start Service[elasticsearch-instance-es-01]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/elasticsearch-es-01 start' returned 1: * Starting Elasticsearch Server es-01
==> default: Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8 but your Java version from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64//bin/java does not meet this requirement
==> default:    ...fail!
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Elasticsearch::Instance[es-01]/Elasticsearch::Service[es-01]/Elasticsearch::Service::Init[es-01]/Service[elasticsearch-instance-es-01]/ensure: change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[elasticsearch-instance-es-01]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/elasticsearch-es-01 start' returned 1: * Starting Elasticsearch Server es-01
==> default: Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8 but your Java version from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64//bin/java does not meet this requirement
==> default:    ...fail!
```

Comment: We need the relevant output to assist.

Comment: Module from Puppet: https://forge.puppet.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch

Comment: instead of specifying the package name in the `java` class, you should be specifying the `version` instead to be platform-agnostic. Is the java class successfully installing `jre-8`?

Comment: Nope, it cannot install this because Ubuntu 14.04 has no official support for JRE8.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: Then a quick google search: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts. Quickly and easily implement that solution in Puppet and you are good to go.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, cool, I knew how to upgrade Java myself but how to do that with Puppet? :)
That's the main problem, not upgrade itself.

I need it to work with Elasticsearch in old vagrant box.

PS. When I upgrade Java myself it runs ok, but after about 3 seconds there is an exception for Access and service stopped. You know how to fix it?